# c assigning string pointer to other string pointer

Tags: c, string, pointers

I have that code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char *str = "aaaaaaaa";
    char *stt = "bbbbbbbb";
    *str = *stt;
    printf("%s\n", str);

return 0;
}
```

it gives me an error:
Access violation writing location,
someone can explain me why and how to over come this?

Comment: it is rewritten prohibited literal string.

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17132248/modifying-the-data-section-in-c/17132278#17132278

Comment: You're not assigning a string pointer to another string pointer. `*str = *stt;` is the same as `str[0] = stt[0];` which attempts to copy the first element from one place to another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

String literals like `"aaaaaaaa"` are read-only, and your code is trying to overwrite the first character of the string pointed to by `str`. If that's what you want to do, you'll need to do something like this:

```
char str[9];
char *stt = "bbbbbbbb";
strcpy(str, "aaaaaaaa");
*str = *stt;
printf("%s\n", str); // prints: baaaaaaa
```

Of course, it's more likely that what you really want is this:

```
str = stt;
printf("%s\n", str); // prints: bbbbbbbb
```

Comment: I'll echo @JensGustedt's comment about declaring your strings as `char const *` instead of `char *`.

Answer (score 3):

You are only assigning the first character, which you shouldn't since string literals are not mutable.

Simply use `str = stt;` to assign the pointers.

BTW, since they are not supposed to be changed, you'd better use `const` qualified types as in

```
char const *str = "aaaaaaaa";
```

Answer (score 0):

A string literal is un-modifiable, i.e, you can't modify a string literal. This is because it is stored on the read only section.

Try this instead

```
char str[] = "aaaaaaaa";
char stt[] = "bbbbbbbb";  

char *pstr = str;
char *pstt = stt;

pstr = pstt;  
printf("%s\n", ptr);
```